# View of my Blender file is completely messed up and I cannot seem to fix it

Tags: rendering, camera

It seems like I am only able to centre my zoom around the camera and no longer with the object I've made. I can't even really zoom in that far at all anymore either. This is my first time trying to make something on Blender so I am very unfamiliar with the program, but none of the suggestions for solutions I've found online have been of any help.

(Also I am on a MacBook)

Comment: Try opening the file, and in the open options (settings) unselect "Load UI".

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Blender!

Have you tried changing the camera lock settings? Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the sidebar. On the right-hand side of the sidebar, press the *View* tab then expand the *View Lock* options.  Here, you can toggle locking to the 3D cursor, to View, or to an object.

If you would like your view to always rotate around the selected object, press, in the top left corner, press *Edit* > *Preferences.* Open the *Navigation* tab, and check *Orbit around selection.* Please note that your viewport will still rotate around the 3D cursor if that option is checked in the sidebar mentioned above.

PS: If you're looking for a good beginner's tutorial series, check out the [Donut Tutorial series by BlenderGuru](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would be solved with the "Show Active" action. You can select the object you want to zoom into and execute the "Show Active" command.

To use Show Active, hit full stop (.) on the number pad.

Since you're on a Macbook and probably don't have a number pad, you should make sure you have "emulate numpad" selected in Preferences>interface>input. Usually, you hit a controller to indicate you're entering numpad emulation, then you use the numbers across the top of your keyboard. (I don't know what controller yours is set to, sometimes it's [backspace], sometimes it's [/].)

You can also create your own keymap options on "keymap" in the same interface tab and assign the "Show Active" action to a particular keystroke.

Good luck.